# Naming convention of worker threads

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, thread, conventions

I started reading about worker threads. Old Legacy worker threads is replaced with worker pools.

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'kworker' 
root          6      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H-kb]
root         20      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H-kb]
root         26      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root         31      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0-mm_]
root         32      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0H-kb]
root         38      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:0H-kb]
root         44      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:0H-kb]
root         71      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:1-mm_]
root         76      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u257:0-]
root        391      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:02 [kworker/0:1H-kb]
root        394      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:01 [kworker/2:1H-kb]
root        395      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:1H-kb]
root        415      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:03 [kworker/3:1H-kb]
root        416      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:1H-kb]
root        418      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1H-kb]
root        869      2  0 04:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u257:1-]
root       9632      2  0 05:49 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0-mm_]
root       9684      2  0 06:00 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0-eve]
root       9685      2  0 06:00 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0-eve]
root       9809      2  0 06:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/5:2-cgr]
root       9885      2  0 06:17 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:0-eve]
root       9915      2  0 06:32 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1-cgr]
root       9937      2  0 06:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1-cgr]
root       9970      2  0 07:14 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u256:2-]
root       9990      2  0 07:31 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u256:1-]
root      10010      2  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:2-eve]
root      10011      2  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1-eve]
root      14977      2  0 07:37 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/4:2-eve]
root      17905      2  0 07:42 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u256:0-]
```

Can anyone provide documentation of the naming convention of kworker/...
For example what is u256:2- in [kworker/u256:2-]

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is : `kworker/%u:%d%s (cpu, id, priority)`
Don't know about the `u`, looks like it designates unbound cpu

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt
[How interpret kworker threads names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152819/how-interpret-kworker-threads-names)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do we have any priority list, like [kworker/0:0H-kb] vs [kworker/3:0-mm_] which is having high priority

Comment: To be honest I am only used to [kworker/0:0H] without anything behind, on which distribution are you ?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 distro

Answer (score 1):

A kworker task name encodes its CPU affinity (if any), an id, its niceness (if any) and the workqueue name or description. Most of the workqueue name is usually truncated because of the relatively small size of the comm field.

For example, the kworker comm field

```
kworker/6:11-mm_
```

means that a kworker kernel thread of CPU 6 with ID 11 executes a work-queue whose name starts with `mm_`.

To get a list of all possible workqueue names one basically has to grep the linux kernel sources, e.g. like this:

```
$ grep 'alloc_workqueue("[^"]\+"' . -ro  | grep '"mm'
./drivers/mmc/core/block.c:alloc_workqueue("mmc_complete"
./drivers/mmc/host/omap.c:alloc_workqueue("mmc_omap"
./drivers/staging/greybus/sdio.c:alloc_workqueue("mmc-%s"
./mm/vmstat.c:alloc_workqueue("mm_percpu_wq"
```

So we are dealing with the `mm_percpu_wq` work-queue here.

---

See also how a kworker task [is created](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L1929):

```
    if (pool->cpu >= 0)
        snprintf(id_buf, sizeof(id_buf), "%d:%d%s", pool->cpu, id,
             pool->attrs->nice < 0  ? "H" : "");
    else
        snprintf(id_buf, sizeof(id_buf), "u%d:%d", pool->id, id);

    worker->task = kthread_create_on_node(worker_thread, worker, pool->node,
                          "kworker/%s", id_buf);
```

So, the `u` character indicates a pool-ID instead of a CPU number (for kworkers without CPU affinity) and `H` indicates a negative nice value.

And see also [how the workqueue name ends up as comm suffix](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L4867).